# DataBound valores de um objeto para TextBox

Tags: c#

Como posso fazer databound de um objeto para os campos do formulário?

A ideia é sempre que preencher o campo "textBox1" atualizar o valor "Nome" do objCliente automaticamente.

Sei que por atribuição direta funciona.

```
objCliente.Nome = textBox1.Text;
```

Mas por DataBound está a dar erro:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", objCliente.Nome, "Text");
```

Comment: tente `textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", objCliente, "Nome");`

Comment: Esta utilizando  WPF?

Comment: Não estou em WPF.

Comment: Qual é o tipo do projeto então? apenas C# não é o suficiente para ter certeza na resposta

Comment: Estou a utilizar wpf